# How to pass int value form aspx.file to .cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:userControl ThreadID='<%# int.Parse( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ThreadID").ToString()) %>' runat="server" id="userControl1" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have a userControl,I want to pass a int value(The 'ThreadID' value ) get from the SqlDataSource to the userControl,but it alway fail.

```
    public partial class userControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        int _ThreadID;
        public int ThreadID
        {
            get { return _ThreadID; }
            set { _ThreadID = value; }
        }
   }
```

Comment: If you want to access usercontrol value to code behind then you can use `YourUserControl.ThreadID`

Comment: But I want to acess ThreadID in aspx file,is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The failed reason seem that I write the code in `Page_Load` function in the usercontrol,and usercontrol get this value after the `Page_Load` over./(ㄒoㄒ)/~~